# How can I conclude from the given relation that consecutive Fibonacci numbers are relatively prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

I've proved  the relation $F_nF_{n-1}=F_n^2-F_{n-1}^2+(-1)^n,n\ge2$ but I'm not getting how can I  conclude that  consecutive Fibonacci numbers are relatively prime from this relation?

Comment: For what it's worth:  it's easy to deduce this from the defining recursion, $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$.  If $p\,|\,\gcd(F_n,F_{n-1})$ then the recursion tells us that $p$ also divides $F_{n-2}$ and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $d>1$ be a common divisor of $F_n$ and $F_{n-1}$ then $d^2$ divides the left-hand side of
$$F_nF_{n-1}-F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2=(-1)^n$$
which is a contradiction because the right-hand side is $(-1)^n$.

Comment: Woww. Nice one.

Comment: This is not really a proof by contradiction: replace the prime $p$ by a common divisor. You obtain that the only common divisors are $\pm1$.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. I revised my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Say $d$ is their $\gcd$, then $F_n = da$ and $F_{n-1}=db$. Now put this into equation and you get $$d^2(ab-a^2+b^2)= (-1)^n$$
Now what can you say for $d$?

Comment: :d has to be $\pm 1$

Comment: Not really. $d$ is by defintion of gcd positive.

Comment: :oops!! It should be 1.